# Phusion Passenger error with rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, phusion

I have a rails 2 app which Im upgading to rails 3. I installed rvm so I can run both the app at the same time.

The rails 3 app works fine. But when I try to revive the rails 2 app I get this error.

```
Processing ApplicationController#index (for 122.179.134.45 at 2012-06-04 09:56:46) [GET]

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)):
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in   `process_request'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:321:in `start_request_handler'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:270:in `handle_spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:149:in `start'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rails_application'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:214:in `block in spawn_rails_application'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:213:in `spawn_rails_application'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:132:in `spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
passenger (3.0.12) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
passenger (3.0.12) helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'

Rendering /var/www/html/dbp/releases/20110518114228/public/500.html (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Any Suggestion?

here are my rvm ruby and rails
    ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [i686-linux]
    Rails 2.3.4

Comment: Did you make sure you're using the same gem versions for the Rails 2 app?

Comment: Different gems. I made it work by running it on webrick as daemon and then reverse proxy it. I just need to reference it while I upgrade it to rails 3. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Although it an old question, and the problem might caused for a different reason for the asker. But I faced the same problem today with passenger (both with apache and nginx), and it was solved by adding the config/secrets.yml file and defining secret keys there.